# How to see the usernames in Firebase authentication web viewerl?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

If you're using the Firebase "Sign in with email", then you can search for emails and see them under the `identifier` in the Firebase authentication web viewer (Admin panel)

I have a custom authentication (username and password, so I'm using the anonymous identifier - If I can disable this identifier, I wouldn't mind). And so under the `identifier` I see `(anonymous)`

I'd like to see the usernames and be able to search for them, if possible. This is the nodejs code creating the custom tokens.

```
const createAuthUser = async function (userId, username, role) {
  // User doesn't exist, create a new user
  try {
    await admin.auth().createUser({
      uid: userId,
      displayName: username,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  try {
    // Set the custom claims for the user
    await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userId, {
      role: role,
    });
    return { status: true };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return { status: false, error: error };
  }
};
```